# Splitting group of $2n$ to couples.

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ boys and $n$ girls in a class.
I'm trying to figure out how many possibilities are there to split them into couples of boy and girl.
 For example, if there are  $2$ boys(A and B) and $2$ girls(C and D) in the class, we could split them:

A with C, B with D or A with D, B with C. We need to split the whole class.
What I was trying to do is to calculate how many ways are there to split into 2's couples(not necessarily boy and girl) in a $2n$ group of students, and then divide by the number of ways to order $2n$ boys and girls in a line where a boy can't sit next to a boy and a girl can't sit next to a girl, but it didn't turn well.

I would love some directions. I do know the final answer is $n!$.

Comment: In how many ways can you choose a partner for the first boy?  Once you've made that choice, how many are left for the second boy?  Continue in this fashion.

Comment: Well, $n$ partners for the first, $(n-1)$ partners for the second.. but, shouldn't I first choose the $n$ boys from the $2n$ students?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In how many ways can $n$ boys and $n$ girls be split into $n$ male/female couples?

Line up the boys in some order, say alphabetically.  We now match girls to boys.  We have $n$ choices for which girl to match to the first boy in line.  For each such choice, we are left with $n - 1$ choices for which remaining of the remaining girls is matched with the second boy in line.  Continuing in this way, we see that there are $n - 2$ choices for which girl is matched with the third boy in line.  In general, there are $n - (k - 1) = n - k + 1$ choices for which girl is matched to the $k$th boy in line. Continue until there is only one girl left to match the last boy in line.  Hence, there are $n!$ ways to form male/female couples.

> In how many ways can $2n$ students be split into $n$ pairs?

Line up the students in some order, say alphabetically.  There are $2n - 1$ choices of which student is matched to the first student in line.  Remove those two students from the line.  There are $2n - 2$ students left in the line.  There are $2n - 3$ choices of which student is matched to the first student remaining in line.  Continuing in this way, we see that there are $2n - 5$ choices for which student is matched to the first student remaining in the line after the first two pairs have been removed.  At the final step, after $n - 1$ pairs of students have been removed from the line, there is only one choice for matching a student with the first student remaining in the line.  Thus, there are 
$$(2n - 1)(2n - 3)(2n - 5) \cdots 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$$
ways to form $n$ pairs of students from $2n$ available students.

Comment: I'm though choosing $n$ boys from $2n$ students. Doesn't that mean that I need to multiply the answe by $\binom{2n}{n}$?

Comment: No.  There are only $n$ boys.  There is only one way to choose all $n$ of them.  Take the $n$ boys as given.  What we are choosing is which girl to match with which boy.  We start with $n$ choices.  Once a girl has been matched with a girl, we are left with $n - 1$ choices for the next match, and so forth.